# Bonjour - find only services on remote machines

Tags: c++, bonjour

Is there a way to tell Bonjour that I need to browse only for services that are not on the local machine?

I've examined `DNSServiceBrowse()`, but I couldn't find parameters that would do that.

Also, since I've written the service as well, I could change how it's registered.

Comment: You mean by programming ? AppleScript / Objective-C ?

Comment: C++ actually, but I assume it is language-agnostic. I'm linking my program to dnssd.dll.